# Streaming (Real-Time) data with observables in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, ngrx

I am building a dashboard that loads data from an API, we don't have live streaming of data, so our solution is to make a http get all 10 seconds.
Our problem is that the Dashboard starts to work very slowly, difficult to click.

I want to know what is the best way to make it without bothering the app for running.
We work also with ngrx/store for updating the data in the Dashboard.
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
timer$: Observable<number> = Observable.timer(0, 10000);
loadBlocksPlantings(reload: boolean = false) {
    if (this.loaderFields$ && !reload) {
      return;
    }
    let numberLoads: number = 0;
    console.log(`FieldsService.loadBlocksPlantings() firstTime... (${new Date()})`);
    this.loaderFields$ = this.timer$.switchMap((time: number) => {
     return Observable.forkJoin(
        [
          this.blocksService.loadBlocksObservable(),
          this.plantingsService.loadPlantingsObservable()
         ]
       );
    })
    .subscribe(
      ([blocks, plantings]: [Block[], Planting[]]) => {
        console.log(`FieldsService.loadBlocksPlantings() loading... (${new Date()})`);
        let blockMap: Map<string, Block> = Map<string, Block>();
        let plantingsMap: Map<string, Planting> = Map<string, Planting>();
        blocks.forEach((block: Block) => {
          blockMap = blockMap.set(block._id, block);
        });
        plantings.forEach((planting: Planting) => {
          plantingsMap = plantingsMap.set(planting._id, planting);
        });
        // Here if already load once next time only update part of the data
        if (numberLoads > 0) {
           this.store.dispatch({type: PLANTINGS_ACTIONS.RELOAD_PLANTINGS, payload: plantingsMap});
           numberLoads++;
           return;
        }
        this.store.dispatch({type: BLOCKS_ACTIONS.ADD_BLOCKS, payload: blockMap});
        this.store.dispatch({
          type: POLYGONS_ACTIONS.ADD_POLYGONS, payload: {
            blocks: blockMap,
            plantings: plantingsMap
          }
        });
        this.store.dispatch({type: PLANTINGS_ACTIONS.ADD_PLANTINGS, payload: plantingsMap});
        numberLoads++;
        this.store.dispatch({type: LOADER_ACTIONS.LOADED});
      }
    );
  }
```